# Group items in WPF WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Using a ListBox with a WrapPanel set as the ItemsPanel, I am trying to achieve what is illustrated in this image:

[image]

However, currently the WrapPanel wraps like this:
[image]

The underlying model looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<IRectangle> Rectangles { get; set; };
}

public class GreenRectangle : IRectangle
{

}

public class BlueRectangle : IRectangle
{

}

public interface IRectangle
{

}
```

The XAML looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GreenRectangle}">
            <Border Background="Green" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BlueRectangle}">
            <Border Background="Green" Height="100px" Width="20px" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

The application is built on: WPF, PRISM, C# 6.0, .NET 4.0 and the MVVM pattern.

Here are some additional requirements/information:

- The width and height of the WrapPanel may change at runtime.
- The width and height of the rectangles are fixed.
- The underlying model guarantees that the items of the Rectangles collection always alternate, that the collection always starts with a GreenRectangle, and that every GreenRectangle is always followed by exactly one BlueRectangle.
- The GreenRectangle and BlueRectangle must be separately selectable.

Is there any way I can achieve what is illustrated on the first image? Can I somehow tell the WrapPanel to always wrap after a BlueRectangle or after an even item index? Or somehow "group" or pair a GreenRectangle with a BlueRectangle? I have looked into using a CollectionView but it doesn't seem to solve what I'm trying to achieve.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The green+blue should be a single item for this, otherwise, well, you can make [own panel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) to arrange layout for pair of items or implementing similar to winforms [`FlowLayoutPanel` break](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5054622/1997232) .

Comment: Well, if you're up for a really cheap solution, just tell the WrapPanel its MaxWidth is whatever the width of 2 blue and green rectangles is. Then it has to wrap the way you want.

Comment: If you feel that an answer helped you, you could [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

To consistently achieve the affect you are looking for switch to a [UniformGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of an `WrapPanel`.

There you can set the amount of Rows and [Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.columns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found that multiple articles with similar issue are pointing to the same thing `UniformGrid`.

[Specify the max number of columns for a WrapPanel in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635431/specify-the-max-number-of-colums-for-a-wrappanel-in-wpf)

and
[Is there an alternative to a WPF WrapPanel that wraps after a certain number of items, not a height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434444/is-there-an-alternative-to-a-wpf-wrappanel-that-wraps-after-a-certain-number-of)

I didn't try then so I'm not sure if they work but since they are both resolved I assume the do work.